# How to call a view by its given ID

Tags: java, android, button, imageview

I have a loop that creates 64 buttons, and within the loop, the button gets an id using `button.setId(n)`

The question is, how do I call the button with a certain id to change its properties.

Ideally, I'm looking for something similar to this

`ImageView button2 = (ImageView)findViewById(button.("with id 14, for example"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the ID, you know the ID. Hence, you call `findViewById()` with the ID you set.

IOW, if you called:

```
button.setId(14);
```

you later call:

```
findViewById(14);
```

Of course, you are welcome to hold your `Button` objects in an array or something and access them that way.

Comment: Ok thanks, but is there anyway to find the id from outside the loop?

Comment: @hazard1994: You are the one setting the IDs. It is up to you to keep track of the ID values you assign.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this: each time you create a button add its reference into a container object like:

```
Map<Integer, ImageView> buttonViews = new HashMap<Integer, ImageView>();
```

To add a button state:

```
ImageView b = new ImageView (this);
buttonViews.put(id, b);
```

To change property to any button:

```
buttonViews.get(id).setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonImage1);
```

In this way you can make various effects...

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been stuck with this problem for ages!